# Showing if two matrices have the same eigenvectors, they commute

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following question:
Let $A,B \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$, then if $A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable and have the same eigenvectors, then $AB = BA$.
I would prefer to know two reasoning: one is a "geometrical" reasoning and one that has algebraic reasoning (so like forming equations to prove this).
Just to consolidate my knowledge on this topic.

I thought that if $A,B$ have the same eigenvectors and are diagonalisable, then that means they must span the same space, so $AB$ is the linear transformation mapping vectors to the same space as $BA$, but I think that doesn't make much sense, so I would appreciate any clarification on this.

Comment: If they are diagonalizable and have the same eigenvectors then in the basis of eigenvectors their linear transformations have diagonal matrices. Diagonal matrices obviously commute, therefore the transformations commute, therefore their matrices in any basis, including the original one, commute. Not sure if this is geometric or algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

You know that

$$A=PUP^{-1}$$

and

$$B=PVP^{-1}$$

for some diagonal $U,V$ (which commute). The matrix $P$ can be made the same since it's made of linearly independent eigenvectors of $A,B$ which are (can be made and ordered) the same.

$$AB=PUP^{-1}PVP^{-1} = PUVP^{-1}=\cdots$$
$$\cdots=PVUP^{-1}=PVP^{-1}PUP^{-1} = BA$$